# Returning 404 in Angular

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

I'm familiar with returning 404 as the HTTP status code when you visit pages that do not exist. When you build static web sites, it works well and it makes sense, but in Angular it's different.

Let's say I visit `/blah` and it's not in my list of routes - then I redirect to `/not-found`. But let's say I visit a valid URL like `/stuff/123` but the object Stuff123 does not exist in my backend. Should I then manually make a redirect in my 
`StuffController` with `$location.path('/not-found')`?

This is my config now:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/stuff/:id', {
        templateUrl: '/views/stuff.html',
        controller: 'StuffController'
    })
    .when('/not-found', {
        templateUrl: '/views/not-found.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/not-found'
    });
});
```

Also, does it make sense to return 404 in Angular? If so, then how do I do that?

Comment: Yes, you can add it to your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I then manually make a redirect in my  StuffController with $location.path('/not-found')?

I would not redirect to not-found route. If object Stuff123 does not exist it still doesn't mean *route is not found*. It *is found*, just no data for this specific parameters. You should just show proper corresponding message.

Or think of this way. Not found is 404 status code. It's *error* code. However, what you describe is not an error situation, it just the absence to the data for this id. Thus in classical application you should have been SUCCESS 200 with just empty response [] for data. So again it's not "not found".

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. How would you display to the user that Stuff123 does not exist?

Answer (score -2):

I know this is kind of old, but I found it easily by looking for 404 and angular so....

I think what you wanted to do way back when was use the 'catch all' route. The catch all route is '**'. So put something like this in your app module...

```
        },
        {
            path: 'admin/orders',
            component: AdminOrdersComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminAuthGuard]
        },
        { path: '**', component: CatchAllComponent }
```

This way in the template you can give your users useful information, no matter what stuff they put into the address bar, after making that mistake.

Comment: This still return a status 200, not a status 404.